# Rotating an off-centered image in Processing

Tags: image, rotation, image-rotation

I'm working on a digital vinyl record player project, and am currently stuck on the vinyl part. I have found many tutorials on how to rotate an image using rotate() and translate(), but all those tutorials take for granted that the image is at the center of the window. My vinyl is not. Help please?

Comment: What have you considered and tried specifically?  In what language?

Comment: All in Processing language. I loaded the image in setup(), and initialized a counter. The image is rotating, but not around its own center. This is what I've got in my draw() method so far, I need help with the math:                                     counter++;
    translate(41-Xposocenter, 34-Yposofcenter);
    rotate(counter*TWO_PI/360);
    //translate(-rc.width/2, -rc.height/2);
    image(rc, 41, 34, 560, 560);

Comment: void draw()
{
  background(0);
  counter++;
  translate(width/2-img.width/2, height/2-img.height/2);
  rotate(counter*TWO_PI/360);
  translate(-img.width/2, -img.height/2);
  image(img,0,0);
}
This code will rotate an image at the center of the window. Idk how to modify the code for it to work when the image is off-centered.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your comment should work:

```
void draw() { 
  background(0); 

  counter++; 

  translate(width/2-img.width/2, height/2-img.height/2); 
  rotate(counter*TWO_PI/360); 
  translate(-img.width/2, -img.height/2); 
  image(img,0,0); 
}
```

To make it easier to handle even more than one image rotating from its centre it might be worth isolating the image's coordinate system using [pushMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html)/[popMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html) (see the [2D Transformations Processing tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) for more details):

```
void draw() { 
  background(0); 
  //draw everything from the centre
  translate(width/2,height/2);

  counter++; 

  //isolate image coordinate system
  pushMatrix();

    //move to centre of image
    translate(img.width/2, img.height/2);
    //rotate from centre
    rotate(counter*TWO_PI/360);
    //translate back to corner
    translate(-img.width/2, -img.height/2);
    //render image
    image(img,0,0);

  //exit image coordinate system, return to Processing's global coordinates
  popMatrix();

}
```